# How to extract data from a broken mycloud gen2

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have a 2TB WD Mycloud GEN2 which I am using for at least 8 years now. The issue is that last week it stopped working while I was copying files. The blue led light inf the front was blinking for a very long time and the device stopped working since then. I have found in the WD forums a link to the next video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OrtHp4eGKI [Use a wd recovery linux image which grants you the ability to scan and fix the FS and recover the firmware] which offers a way to fix the device. I have tried this solution but the main issue is that I have recently upgraded the device firmware from 2.x to 5.x and the size of the firmware is more then 100 MB ie 161 MB. The fix in the video won't work to fix the broken device but it offers a linux shell with busybox in it.

Later on I have found the next video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz6htftDi-0 [Open the device and extract the 3.5 inch WD Nas sata disk and connect it to a PC using an external case] which offers to open the device and move the disk to an external enclosure to access the data.

Probably the HDD is about to die since it has read IO errors. I am looking for a way to extract the data from the linux recovery shell if possible to prevent the HDD from dying while moving physically the device.

Comment: Can you precis what steps you have avctually taken rather than just provide links to videos? This is for two reasons - a) people can read the precis in 30 seconds rather than plod through 15 minutes of video, & b) if the links ever go down, there's nothing to know what you did at all.

Comment: Eventually What I did was to extract the HDD from the case like the second video suggested, it's far easier for me then other solutions.(And the device is not under warranty)